# How to solve peerinvalid errors in npm install?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, jasmine, physicsjs

I'm trying to follow the steps to contribute to PhysicsJS (https://github.com/wellcaffeinated/PhysicsJS#contributing) and having the following error during `npm install`.

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt-contrib-jasmine does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs@0.1.10 wants grunt-contrib-jasmine@~0.5.3
npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/slacktracer/Dropbox/dev/PhysicsJS
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/slacktracer/Dropbox/dev/PhysicsJS/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Any suggestions on how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like PhysicsJS's package.json needs to be updated so that `"grunt-contrib-jasmine": "0.4.x",` is `"grunt-contrib-jasmine": "0.5.x",` in the `devDependencies`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case (peerinvalid problem, but different modules) I had to uninstall the module first and then install it again:

```
npm uninstall MODULE
npm install MODULE
```

I also specified a fixed version for the MODULE in the package.json because before I had a version range:

```
"MODULE": "1.42.2",
```